# The 'Use Client' directive in NextJS using TurboRepo is causing a loader error, "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, monorepo, turborepo

This is the error

```js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:23)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export class OrgClient extends BaseClient {
|   
>   async getOrgs(orgName?: string): Promise<Org[]> {
|     const endpoint = orgName ? `/orgs?org_name=${orgName}` : `/orgs`;
|     return this.fetchData(endpoint);

Import trace for requested module:
../../packages/ui/src/clients/orgClient.ts
../../packages/ui/src/index.tsx
./src/app/page.tsx
```

Has anyone come across this issue before?  I am using the standard template, all I did was just put in some TS files in to the already made UI package in the TurboRepo NextJS template.

```js
'use client'
import { RestaurantCard as Card } from "ui";
import { Org, OrgClient } from "ui";
```

I am sure this is a simple bundler issue of some sort, I am just not familiar with what it could be.  NextJS is new to me.